# Which variable enters the basis from $\hat c$ in the revised Simplex method?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I had an issue understanding wich matrix enters the bases in a linear programing exercise done during a lecture : the variable that entered the basis is one which has negative coefficient in $\hat c$ in the case of a $\max$ problem.

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\max \ & 2x_1&+ 3x_2\\
&3x_1&+5x_2&\le 15\\
&4x_1&+x_2&\le 8\\
&x_1&+x_2&\ge 1\\
\forall i, x_i
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$$

was transformed with slack variables into :

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\max \ & 2x_1&+ 3x_2\\
&3x_1&+5x_2&+x_3&&&= 15\\
&4x_1&+x_2&&+x_4&&= 8\\
&x_1&+x_2&&&+x_5&= 1\\
\forall i, x_i
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$$

I think there is a mistake in the last line, shouldn't it be : $-x_1-x_2+x_5= 1$? Because it leads me to an absurdity about which variable enters the matrix when doing revised simplex method:

\begin{align*}
\hat{c} &= c -\Pi A\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
3& 5 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
4 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\hat{c}&=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

**Then it was said that $x_5$ enters the matrix. Yet, its coefficient is negative in $\hat c$.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of the formulation in standard form is wrong. It should read $x_1+x_2-x_5 = 1$ ($x_5$ is subtracted as an excess variable).

Indeed $x_5$ enters the basis since the coefficient is negative and it is a $\max$ problem. No contradiction there.